# jQuery working in console but not when loading website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is the code that is perfectly working in console:

```
jQuery(".cf7_wrap_com li").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).find(".first_univer input").click(function(){
            var label1 = jQuery(this).parent().find("label").html();    
            if( jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
                   jQuery(this).parent().find(".first_high").show();
                         jQuery(".cf7_wrap_com li").not( jQuery(this).parent().parent() ).each(function(){        
                            jQuery(this).find(".first_high").hide();      
                         });
                             }

            else {}
             });
        });
```

and the code below is what I saved in my custom js file and not working on website load

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
    jQuery(".cf7_wrap_com li").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).find(".first_univer input").click(function(){
            var label1 = jQuery(this).parent().find("label").html();    
            if( jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
                   jQuery(this).parent().find(".first_high").show();
                         jQuery(".cf7_wrap_com li").not( jQuery(this).parent().parent() ).each(function(){        
                            jQuery(this).find(".first_high").hide();      
                         });
                             }

            else {}
             });
        });
    });
});
```

I also want to know if it is possible to trim this code as I think I might have added something which unnecessary.

I am using it on two radio buttons(which are inactive by default) and when a user clicks on either of them a short form opens.

Here's the image:

[image]

And this is the `html`:

```
<h1>What type of student?</h1>
<ul class="cf7_wrap_com first_use">
<li>
<div class="highschoolform first_univer"><input id="#school" name="School" type="radio" value="highschool" /> <label for="highschool">High School</label>
<div class="cf7_wrap_hs first_high">[contact-form-7 id="3552" title="High school"]</div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="unversityform first_univer"><input id="#University" name="School" type="radio" value="University" /> <label for="University">University</label>
<div class="cf7_wrap_uni first_high">[contact-form-7 id="3553" title="University"]</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in the developer console? What's your HTML - are you loading jQuery before the script that requires jQuery?

Comment: I just posted the HTML. I am not getting any error message in dev. console. To make it load after the script I have added load function(may this is where I am doing it wrong)

Comment: have you include jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. give the radios a class
2. use closest and siblings

```js
$(function() {
  $(".school").on("click",function() {
    $(this).closest("ul").find(".first_high").hide();
    $(this).siblings(".first_high").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.first_high { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>What type of student?</h1>
<ul class="cf7_wrap_com first_use">
  <li>
    <div class="highschoolform first_univer">
      <input id="#school" class="school" name="School" type="radio" value="highschool" />
      <label for="highschool">High School</label>
      <div class="cf7_wrap_hs first_high">[contact-form-7 id="3552" title="High school"]</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="unversityform first_univer">
      <input id="#University" class="school" name="School" type="radio" value="University" />
      <label for="University">University</label>
      <div class="cf7_wrap_uni first_high">[contact-form-7 id="3553" title="University"]</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Radio buttons still not working. I guess it is a problem with scripts not loading after my page or something but can't figure out.

http://i.imgur.com/ZnFz40t.gif

Comment: It is working perfectly in console without showing any errors and there are still no errors when I am loading the site after saving it in my js file

Comment: name/class/id conflict? Add console.log inside the click

Comment: Hey, @mplungjan thanks for the help. The problem it was not running was because of an id conflict. Fixed it and now it works like a charm.